# Split text in JME and assign values in an array

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to create an array in j2me with split text. I'm trying to use the StringTokenizer class from ostermiller.org. However I can't figure out how to assign the tokens into an array. What could be wrong with this code?

```
String[] myToken;
StringTokenizer tokenObject;
tokenObject = new StringTokenizer("one-two-three","-");
myToken= tokenObject.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a loop that checks if there are more tokens and in the loop gets the next token.

Try this:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("one-two-three", "-");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    // Do something with variable "token"
}
```